# nested static builder class, further explanation on its plumbing

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder, effective-java

```
public class MyPojo{
    String required;
    Integer optionalOne;
    Integer optionalTwo;

    private MyPojo(Builder builder){
        this.required = builder.required
        this.optionalOne = builder.one;
        this.optionalTwo = builder.two;
    }

    public static class Builder{

        String required;
        Integer optionalOne =0;
        Integer optionalTwo =0;

        public Builder(String req){
            this.required = req;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder optionalOne(Integer one){
            this.one = one;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder optionalTwo(Integer two){
            this.two = two;
            return this;
        }
        public MyPojo build(){
            return new MyPojo(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Which is then called like this :

```
MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo.Builder("req").optionalOne(1).optionalTwo(2).build();
```

Which is all lovely, but I don't understand a couple of parts.

There are two **New** statements one in the calling statement and one in the `build()` method, but there is only one new object created ?

Also, if I then call a second time , without second optional paremeter :

`MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo.Builder("req").optionalOne(1).build();`

Why will optionalTwo revert back to default value (zero). And not keep the value passed in first time(2), its a static class so one instance shared between all MyPojos ?

Comment: can't see the `MyPojo()` constructor declared. Don't you have some code missing?

Comment: This does not compile. Please post your actual code.

Comment: I checked your code and there's a `}` missing somewhere.

Comment: To answer your questions. (i) No, two objects are created, a Builder and a MyPojo. The Builder object is temporary and becomes eligible for gc after the `build()` call completes (ii) `Builder` is `nested static class` of `MyPojo`, its instances are not shared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bit:

```
 new MyPojo().Builder("req")
```

should be:

```
 new MyPojo.Builder("req")
```

So you first create a `Builder`, and then the `Build` method (which would be better as `build` btw) creates the immutable object.

If you create a second instance, that's entirely separate from the first. Don't be fooled by the `Builder` class being declared as static - that just means that an instance of `Builder` doesn't have an implicit "parent" `MyPojo` class reference associated with it. The fields of separate `Builder` instances are still entirely separate.

Comment: well, `MyPojo.Builder()` is not declared, so there is string argument missed somewhere. If that is fixed, code is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @pupssman there were other errors before I edited the question, e.g. the builder methods were not returning `this`. Thanks for the downvote.

Answer (score -1):

There are several errors here. As written it does not even compile.

Look up [Fluent Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) for how it is supposed to work. Now consider

```
MyPojo myPojo = new MyPojo.Builder(req).optionalOne(1).optionalTwo(2).Build();
```

(this is not what you have, this is what you *should* have)

This is how it works:

1. `new MyPojo.Builder(req)` creates a MyPojo.Builder object and assigns the passed req to `this.required`
2. `.optionOne(1)` assigns 1 to `MyPojo.Builder.optionalOne`. It then returns the same Object (`return this`). This is the key, because it allows the next step
3. `.optionOne(2)` assigns 2 to `MyPojo.Builder.optionalTwo` to the `MyPojo.Builder` object returned by the previous call. Note that we are still working with the same `Builder` object created in step 1. `this` is returned again
4. `Build()` calls `Build` method on the `Builder`, which in turn calls the `MyPojo` constructor. This method should be called `build` to conform to Java naming conventions.

EDIT: The code is not compilable. 
EDIT2: Detailed explanation